# "Subscribe to category"-form in Wordpress, but use logged in users' email

Tags: php, wordpress, email, mailchimp, subscription

I've looked around for tips and plugins to achieve what I would like to achieve... Not finding the perfect solution, I'll try ask here.

I'm building a WP website where most pages will be visible only for logged in users. On a category page, I would like to put a button/widget where the logged in user can subscribe to that specific category.

It would be easy to create a signup form where the user puts his/her email adress and clicks "Subscribe". But since the user is already a member, and logged in, I think it would be much more user friendly if the user doesn't have to write their email address again.

So the ultimate scenario would be that the user only clicks a button, and then the member/user data (email address) is sent to either a list, a csv-file or to a list/group in MailChimp.

Any help or tips would be SO appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you review yout question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to make a button for subscribe where the user shouldn't add anything else but a click, if that's the case you can achieve so by using the wordpress function

```
<?php get_userdata( $user_email ); ?>
```

you can also list everything from users account with the function.

If you want to make a subscription for just 1 category I wouldn't be able to help.

UPDATE:
Looks like the wp plugin JetPack can do this too I think you must try it, just note that since it's plugin by Automattic you will need to do account in wordpress.com and relate to it when you install the plugin in your wordpress self-hosted installation to get it in rails.

Comment: Thank you so much knif3r! Maybe someone else has some tips about the category stuff - but this was helpful to solve part of the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to btw I've updated the answer, I hope that works fine for you.

Comment: Emma did you tried what I've added in the answer, and if so did it worked?

Comment: Thanks knif3r for the update! I haven't had time to try it out, but I certainly will, and I'll let you know if it worked out!

Comment: Actually I've found out on the way, that I had to use a membership plugin instead of registered WP users. So I can't use the code above, but thanks a lot anyway for all your help!